# Not able to Clamp my camera rotation value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clamp

I made a camera that rotates around an object... Everything is working fine. But I was not able to clamp or restrict the camera rotation. Here's the code..

```
//First - Get the Initial Position
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            mPreviousPosition = mCamRef.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }

        //Second - the difference amount and change in x
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = mCamRef.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 direction = mPreviousPosition - newPosition;
            
            float rotationAroundYAxis = -direction.x * 180;
            mCamRef.transform.position = mTargetToRotateAround.position;
            rotationAroundYAxis = Mathf.Clamp(rotationAroundYAxis, -60f,60f);
            
            mCamRef.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * rotationAroundYAxis);

            mCamRef.transform.Translate(new Vector3(mDistanceToTarget.x, mDistanceToTarget.y, -mDistanceToTarget.z));
            mPreviousPosition = newPosition;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clamping

```
rotationAroundYAxis = Mathf.Clamp(rotationAroundYAxis, -0.6f, 0.6f);
```

but then use it for [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) which rotates from the current rotation about the given amount => you always rotate something.

You would probably rather use e.g. [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)

```
mCamRef.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * rotationAroundYAxis);
```

However, note that clamping a rotation using `+- 0.6°` makes barely any sense ...

From you comments you want to clamp to +-60° so rather use

```
rotationAroundYAxis = Mathf.Clamp(rotationAroundYAxis, -60, 60);
```

Though I still don't understand how you want to get a rotation in angles from a direction vector ...

Comment: Hi @derHugo, Hope you're doing good. So, I'm clamping the rotation by +- 0.6f because anyways all my values are at this point are being converted to screentoviewportPoint.So when I debug.log my rotationAroundYAxis which is the cause of rotation i figured -+0.6 is how much I want this value. Thus, i wrote that. Correct me if I'm wrong..Thanks

Comment: No .. you are applying this rotation to a transform not any screen or viewport point  .. and, well you know 1° is very little ... 180° is half of a circle ;)

Comment: Im sorry im finding it difficult to understand this. You said im applying the rotation to a tranform. So here are you referring to the ```rotationAroundYAxis variable``` as the transform or something else.... And here's what im actually trying to do and tried to do in this.... I need a camera that rotates around an object which we assign in the inspector... So keeping that as a center point i want my camera to rotate +60 and -60 around. But not a full complete rotation..So i thought ill do this 180degree and then look at the values and clamp it according to the needs later on.

Comment: Then use -60 and 60 to clamp, not 0.6 which is wrong by a factor of 100 ;) And no, what I mean is you are passing this value into `transform.Rotate` or in my code `transform.rotation` .. that's where you apply it to a transform.

Comment: I have updated my question.... Let me know if its correct. But when playing it the camera is super jittery / shaky and its not changing its position instead staying the the same position as of when we click the play button

Comment: Hi @derHugo. After a couple of messing around. I just wrote a new code overall & it solved my issue. Thanks :D